# Segment progressbar android

Tags: android, video, progress-bar

I'd like to let the users of my app the possibility to choose a fragment of a video (before editing it). I'd like to build a similar activity that WhatsApp has, in order to cut a video before editing it:

[image]

But I don't know how to adapt the progressbar view in order to have two differents points in the time to get the desired segment of video.

Any idea? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this, might be what you are looking for:

https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/

Comment: Thanks!! Exactly what I was searching!!